# How to check if view file exist in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter v3.

In the controller file i want to check if view file exist or not.

```
$file = "login";

$this->load->view($file, array(),true);
```

The code giving me error

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: login.php
```

Comment: Shouldn't one part of the code be able to expect that other parts of the code are present?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart most of the time I'd agree with you. However, there may be use cases in which you need to check if a case-specific (custom) view exists and display that or else display a generic one. I have a specific use case very similar to that on a site I developed for a customer. Can't go into much detail because I'm behind an NDA, but I actually needed to do exactly this at one point

Comment: The error is saying that not file named view.php is found in the _/application/view/_ folder. Checking that a "view" file exists is only a problem during development. As a developer, you are expected to supply valid values. If the user enters a non-existent resource, i.e. an non-existent page, view. whatever, CodeIgniter will display a 404 page not found view.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `file_exists($file);`
but in case having absolute paths without hard coding it.
you can use `dirname(__FILE__)`

```
$link = dirname(__FILE__) . '/include.php';
if (realpath($link)) {
    include($link);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Native PHP has the answer:
`file_exists()` ([see PHP documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)) allows you to check whether if a file exists in your filesystem or not.

Simply put, you'd need:

```
if (file_exists(base_url('views/file.php')))
{
  // do something if view file exists
}

else
{
  // do some other thing if file is not present
}
```

Comment: actually i am looking specifically  for codeigniter framwork

Comment: codeigniter does not have a specific method that does that. Remember framworks are not a complete language implementation/rewrite, just a set of tools that make your life easier. Why wouldn't a native PHP function suit you?

Comment: My final question is basically because CI doesn't extend PHP functionality. It just wraps it. If there was (there isn't) a CI method for this, in the background it would be using the same native PHP calls. Having said that, the CI File Helper does include some file functions which, although not really aimed at checking if a file exists or not, could be used for that. Read [File Helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html) in the CI documentation

Comment: yes you are right.  I just wanted to know if Codeigniter have dedicated function for it or not.

Comment: There isn't a specific one, but the file helper provides `get_file_info()` and `read_file()`, both of which have other purposes but will return `false` if the file does not exist so in a way, they could be used to check if the file exists or not (they do have bigger overhead than just using `file_exists()` though)

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to override the function which is responsible for loading the views

create a class `MY_Loader` in your `application/core` folder.

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {

        foreach (array('_ci_view', '_ci_vars', '_ci_path', '_ci_return') as $_ci_val)
        {
            $$_ci_val = isset($_ci_data[$_ci_val]) ? $_ci_data[$_ci_val] : FALSE;
        }

        $file_exists = FALSE;

        // Set the path to the requested file
        if (is_string($_ci_path) && $_ci_path !== '')
        {
            $_ci_x = explode('/', $_ci_path);
            $_ci_file = end($_ci_x);
        }
        else
        {
            $_ci_ext = pathinfo($_ci_view, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $_ci_file = ($_ci_ext === '') ? $_ci_view.'.php' : $_ci_view;

            foreach ($this->_ci_view_paths as $_ci_view_file => $cascade)
            {
                if (file_exists($_ci_view_file.$_ci_file))
                {
                    $_ci_path = $_ci_view_file.$_ci_file;
                    $file_exists = TRUE;
                    break;
                }

                if ( ! $cascade)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! $file_exists && ! file_exists($_ci_path))
        {
            throw new Exception('View file '.$view.' doesn\'t exist.');
        }
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }

}
```

it throws now an exception - the only thing you have to do - is to catch it

```
try
{
    $file = "login";
    $this->load->view($file, array(),true); 
}
catch(\Throwable $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> if you use PHP < 7 you need to catch an Exception instead of the Throwable Interface.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   if(! file_exists(APPPATH."views"."/$foldername/$filename.php") ) 
   redirect(base_url()); //or anything you want
```